# Windows 7: get batch file to resize popup window

Tags: batch-file, popup, cmd

I'm trying to create a large popup window from a batch file to display what the next action user needs to take before continuing. I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to try it out.

Here is what I got so far:

```
set USERS=(user1, user2)
set MESSAGE=some really long message here...... like 15 line.

for %%i in %USERS% do msg /Time:10 /w %%i %MESSAGE%
```

So all I need is to do is be able to resize the popup window and that's all I need for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can re-size a popup window in batch, so you may have to either use another scripting language or create a small executable to replace the msg command.  The executable could accept text, horizontal size, and vertical size parameters, and would then display the message.  It could also return the result, if needed.  You could replace `msg /Time:10 /w %%i %MESSAGE%` in your code with `start SizedPopup.exe "A really long message", 200, 200` to create a message box with the text "A really long message" that is 200 by 200 pixels.  You can probably find such a program by googling, although I believe this would be fairly easy to write in any scripting language.

Comment: Can I actually leave the %MESSAGE% part in for that SizedPopup.exe or do I need to have a string with "..."?

Comment: Actually, that start command doesn't seem to be working for me... :( I end up with "the system cannot find the file SizedPopup.exe

Comment: You should be able to leave it. Assuming it is a variable, the command processor will replace it with the actual value at runtime.  You must provide the exe and the path for it to work, unless the exe is in the same directory as the batch script.

Comment: Oh, I see, I have to download that application? I need something more generic so that all windows users can use this batch file.

Comment: Yeah, you would either have to write or download the exe.  Although you could have the batch script download it from a server automaticly.

Comment: Is it possible to have a more traditional Windows style window popup from a batch file instead??

Comment: I don't think so.  I believe a batch file can only display popups with msg without an external program.